# biblatex output like REVTeX style

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` 2.0 and Biber. A multiple-entry citation using `\mcite` gives as output:

> [1] a) Author 1, Phys. Rev. Lett. 11, 1 (2012); b) Author 2,
>   Phys. Rev. Lett. 22, 2 (2012).

but I would like to have the output like some REVTeX styles, in which consecutive citations on the same journal appears as "ibid."

> [1] a) Author 1, Phys. Rev. Lett. 11, 1 (2012); b) Author 2,
>   ibid. 22, 2 (2012).

Is there a simple way to get this automatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multiple-entry citations via `\mcite` and friends are implemented using entry sets. Bibliography items for entry sets are generated by the `set` driver. This driver depends on the style, but in general it contains the code:

```
\entryset{<precode>}{<postcode>}
```

For each member of the set, `\entryset` executes `<precode>`, the `entrytype`-specific driver and `<postcode>`. The `entrysetcount` field keeps track of the entry currently being processed in the set.

To introduce abbreviations, you can modify the `set` driver to track the first author list and title. The `author` and `journal` bibliography macros can then perform abbreviations where appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,mcite,subentry,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}

\makeatletter

% Based on definition in numeric.bbx
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset
    {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
        \setunit*{\addnbspace}}
       {}}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{1}
       {\savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}%
        \savefield{journaltitle}{\bbx@lastjournal}}
       {}}%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\bbx@lastjournal
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

% Based on definition in biblatex.def
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}
    {\nopunct}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \ifboolexpr{ test \ifuseauthor and not test {\ifnameundef{author}} }
       {\printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
           \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
       {}}
    {}}

% Based on definition in biblatex.def
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {\iffieldequals{journaltitle}{\bbx@lastjournal}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}
          {}
          {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
       {\global\undef\bbx@lastjournal
        \printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield{journalsubtitle}}}}}

\makeatother

% Some additional formatting to conform with desired output
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
       \step[fieldset=title,null]
       \step[fieldset=pages,null]
       \step[fieldset=series,null]
       \step[fieldset=issue,null]
       \step[fieldset=month,null]
    }
  }
}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1}\bibrightparen}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{glashow:quark,
  title = {Where is the Top Quark?},
  author = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  journal = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  volume = {45},
  issue = {24},
  pages = {1914--1916},
  year = {1980},
  month = {Dec}}
@article{weinberg:muon,
  title = {Muon Absorption in Liquid Hydrogen},
  author = {Weinberg, Steven},
  journal = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  volume = {4},
  pages = {575--578},
  year = {1960}}
@article{wilson,
  title = {Obedience},
  volume = {77},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  author = {Wilson, Daniel},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {47--59}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Define a set with common author \mcite{set1,*glashow,*glashow:quark}.
Define a set with common journal \mcite{set2,*gillies,*wilson}.
Define a set with common author and journal \mcite{set3,*weinberg,*weinberg:muon}.
Define a set with no common author or journal \mcite{set4,*bertram,*reese}.
Define a set with common author \mcite{set5,*knuth:ct,*knuth:ct:a}.
Filler text \cite{knuth:ct:b,glashow,glashow:quark,weinberg,weinberg:muon}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- Abbreviations are applied only for recurrent names and titles from the first member of an entry set. The solution can be adapted to other schemes, but these might be prone to ambiguities.
- The `namehash` field uniquely identifies the truncated `labelname` list. To consider all names in the list, use `fullhash` instead.

Comment: I'm currently working on a REVTeX-like style for `biblatex`, hopefully ready by the weekend. If it's OK, I'll add this in: I'd not noticed this particular feature!

Comment: @JosephWright Certainly. I [posted in the meta thread on licensing](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1755) awhile back.

Comment: Hi. Another useful feature in REVTex is the omission of subsequent same author(s), as for example:

Comment: (I couldn't edit the previous comment)  [1] a) Author 1 and Author 2, Phys. Rev. Lett. 11, 1 (2012); b) Author 1 and Author 2, Phys. Rev. Lett. 22, 2 (2012).  is presented simply as  [1] a) Author 1 and Author 2, Phys. Rev. Lett. 11, 1 (2012); b) 22, 2 (2012).

Comment: @M.N.Tamashiro I've made an edit. For any further requirements you might want to wait for Joseph's style to release or open up a new question.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks: always best to ask :-) I've got a few rearrangements of the location of volume numbers, then should have something to CTAN as `biblatex-phys`.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks again! I commented about the additional feature, since it might be included in the REVTeX-like style for biblatex.

Comment: @JosephWright Good to know. I'm not familiar with this style, but if citations are a mix of individual entries and entry sets you'll want to throw an additional `\global\undef\bbx@*` in there.

Comment: @JosephWright There is a small problem when two subsequent bibentries share the same author and/or journal. It behaves like the different independent entries are subentries of the same bibentry. In the above example, if [3a] and [3b] are split into [3] and [4], the bibentry [4] would not display author and journal (but it should).

Comment: @M.N.Tamashiro I hope that the solution I've adopted will deal correctly with this case. I've sent the code to CTAN: look out for `biblatex-phys` appearing soon.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I'll look it out and test it.

Comment: @M.N.Tamashiro The problem is the missing `\undef` I mentioned. I've made a correction for completeness, but in the end the solution should be to simply use `biblatex-phys`.

Comment: @M.N.Tamashiro No problem. BTW: You're among the first askers to use biblatex 2.0. [Feedback](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues) on this release is most welcome.